# Networked Activity Monitor for CPU monitoring?

Tags: performance, cpu, activity-monitor, monitoring, snmp

I would like to track computer A's CPU (and maybe memory etc) usage on computer B in a GUI similar to that of Activity Monitor. Is that possible? Preferably a free solution. I have looked at SNMP but can't find any clients similar to Activity Monitor (or free).

Comment: Simple: Screen Sharing to other Mac and run Activity Monitor. For SNMP monitoring (rather different in scope), I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to `ssh` from B to A and run any number of monitoring tools such as `top` or https://htop.dev/.

You could also use a 3rd party utility such as [Watchman](https://support.watchmanmonitoring.com/hc/en-us).

Comment: SSH is not a GUI-solution.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with SNMP monitoring:

As far as I know, there is no *easy* SNMP solution (free or otherwise). I use [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net) to monitor my Macs via SNMP.

Cacti is free, but complex for just casual monitoring. I run it in a linux virtual machine (I would use a raspberry pi if starting again). Out of the box it can monitor network usage (by interface, not by process) and load average on a Mac with net-snmp running. To extend that to CPU, memory, temperatures, etc. I use a bit of python scripting.

I would only recommend if you would find it a fun project.
[image]